# How to get data from json_encoded data from mysql in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing data in json format in mysql database table column like

table A

column-user_details

```
"{\"name\":\"sadasfsf\",\"phone\":\"7896521747\",\"address_1\":\"dvgsdsd\",\"state_name\":\"g\",\"city_name\":\"sdgds\",\"zip_code\":\"ghdfh\"}"
```

I am fetching data like

```
json_decode($variable, true);


<?php echo $variable['name'];?>
```

However I am getting error like

Illegal string offset 'name'

Comment: `json_last_error` and `json_last_error_msg` exist, so _use them_ to go and check whether decoding your JSON worked in the first place.

Comment: The data looks like it's been double-encoded when it was saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first parameter of json_decode is not a parameter passing by reference, so if you want to get the json code as php array, you mast adding the result of json_decode into a variable.

```
<?php

$variable = "{\"name\":\"sadasfsf\",\"phone\":\"7896521747\",\"address_1\":\"dvgsdsd\",\"state_name\":\"g\",\"city_name\":\"sdgds\",\"zip_code\":\"ghdfh\"}";

$array = json_decode($variable, true);

echo $array['name'];
```

**NB:** json_decode() is a php code, so you must use it after <?php tag, not outside of it

Comment: Please help me how to remove the forward slashes while json encoding

Comment: why did you want to remove the backslashes ?

Comment: I need to remove the trailing slashes whn inserting in database as json format. How can I do that?

Comment: @Abhishek To know that we'd have to see what, and how you're saving it. I suggest you should ask a new question about that specific issue.

Comment: as ADyson said, i suggest to ask new question about that, and i hope if my response help, i will be appreciated if you accept my response.